# Get absolute path of DOM link

Tags: php, dom

I want to get the absolute path/realpath of a link in a DOM element.

Let's say that I want to have the realpath of the `src` of an `img` tag:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('files/file.html');
$dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->getAttribute('src');
```

As resource of an img tag may occour (if the DOM is inside files):

```
https://www.domain.it/files/images/image.png
images/image.png
../images2/image2.png
../../images3/image3.png
```

How can I get the absolute path / realpath from the DOM link in order to handle it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you know site address where you are getting this image from, you can try using [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) php function

```
$url = $siteUrl . '/' . realpath($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->getAttribute('src'));
```